# MvxTabsFragmentActivity - Remove tabs

Tags: mvvmcross

**Is there any way to remove tabs from an MvxTabsFragmentActivity-inherited class?** I mean, currently there's only `AddTab<T>()` method for adding tabs. **But, what if I want to remove tabs?**

TIA,

Pap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - MvxTabsFragmentActivity doesn't provide any `RemoveTab` functionality currently.

The source for this activity is https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging/MvxTabsFragmentActivity.cs - you should be able to use this as a starting point for your own needs.

Comment: Thanks @Stuart. What I wanted was to be able to remove all tabs. I couldn't inherit from MvxTabsFragmentActivity or add my method as an extension method because all the fundamental members needed are private. So I just copied MvxTabsFragmentActivity.cs to my project and added my own method.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
After following @Stuart's advice and-as I mentioned in my comment below-I added the source code for the MvxTabsFragmentActivity class to my project and added the following method-to remove all tabs-which was all I wanted:

```
public void RemoveAllTabs()
        {
            // First, detach the curent tab using SupportFragmentManager object.
            if (_currentTab != null)
            {
                var tag = _currentTab.CachedFragment.Tag;

                _currentTab.CachedFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag( tag );

                if (_currentTab.CachedFragment != null && !_currentTab.CachedFragment.IsDetached)
                {
                    var ft = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    ft.Detach( _currentTab.CachedFragment );
                    ft.Commit();
                    SupportFragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions();
                }
            }

            // Second remove all tabs from TabHost object
            if (_tabHost != null)
                _tabHost.ClearAllTabs();

            // And lastly, empty our _lookup table(actually a Dictionary).
            _lookup.Clear();

            _currentTab = null; // Clear the current tab
        }
```

I guess if someone wanted to have a specific tab removed he could use the `SupportFragmentManager` object and have something like this:

```
public void RemoveTab( string tag )
{
    var fragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag( tag );

    if (fragment != null && ! fragment.IsDetached)
    {
        var ft = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Detach( fragment );
        ft.Commit();
        SupportFragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions();

        //_tabHost.TabWidget.RemoveView( fragment.View ); // Neither this..
        //_tabHost.RemoveView( fragment.View );           // .. or this removed the tab from the Tabhost.

    }
}
```

**However, although the above code was successful at removing the fragment/view inside the tab, the tab itself remained-showing a blank/empty tab.** I couldn't find a `TabHost.RemoveTab()` or `TabHost.TabWidget.RemoveTab()` methods and the `TabHost.RemoveView()`/`TabHost.TabWidget.RemoveView()` did not work.

**Notes:** I renamed the MvxTabsFragmentActivity to something else and included all copyright notices at the top of the class in my project. Thanks again to @Stuart.