# java.lang.IllegalStateException with mvxlistview and mvx adapter

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

we are working with  mvvmcross 3.1.1. However there is an issue every once in a while in the android version. The following exception is thrown however we are not able to reproduce every time. I have also added our custom adapter and listview. If you notice anything which can result in the exception please do tell :)
The data is binded through xml.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(16908298, class cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.droid.views.MvxListView) with Adapter(class cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.droid.views.MvxAdapter)]
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1656)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3904)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3715)
at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:4123)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7811)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:7569)
at android.widget.ListView.dispatchTouchEvent(ListView.java:4494)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2169)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1613)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2539)
at cirrious.crosscore.droid.views.MvxEventSourceActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(MvxEventSourceActivity.java)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2117)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8005)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3688)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3738)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3818)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3715)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3875)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3688)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3738)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3715)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3688)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5947)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5920)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5883)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6031)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:214)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Custom adapter

```
   namespace MissionsApp.App.Droid.Controls
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;

    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Views;

    using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views;
    using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;

    using MissionsApp.App.Model;
    using MissionsApp.Core.ViewModels.Items;

    public class MvxSectionAdapter : MvxAdapter
    {
        private int _itemTemplateHeaderId;
        private int _itemTemplateFooterId;



        public MvxSectionAdapter(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {

        }

        public int ItemTemplateHeaderId
        {
            get { return this._itemTemplateHeaderId; }
            set
            {
                if (this._itemTemplateHeaderId == value)
                    return;
                this._itemTemplateHeaderId = value;

                // since the template has changed then let's force the list to redisplay by firing NotifyDataSetChanged()
                if (this.ItemsSource != null)
                    this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        public int ItemTemplateFooterId
        {
            get { return this._itemTemplateFooterId; }
            set
            {
                if (this._itemTemplateFooterId == value)
                    return;
                this._itemTemplateFooterId = value;

                // since the template has changed then let's force the list to redisplay by firing NotifyDataSetChanged()
                if (this.ItemsSource != null)
                    this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool UseLastItemAsFooter { get; set; }
        public MvxSectionListView ListView { get; set; }

        public override void NotifyDataSetChanged()
        {
            this.NotifyDataSetChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }

        public override void NotifyDataSetChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.NotifyDataSetChanged(e);

            var handler = this.DataSetChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }

        protected override void SetItemsSource(IEnumerable value)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                var list = new List<object>();
                foreach (ISectionViewModel section in value)
                {

                    list.Add(new MvxHeaderSectionListItem(section as MvxViewModel));
                    for (int i = 0; i < section.Count; i++)
                    {
                        MvxViewModel viewModel = (MvxViewModel) section.Get(i);
                        var islast = i == section.Count - 1;
                        list.Add(islast && this.UseLastItemAsFooter
                            ? (object) new MvxFooterSectionListItem(viewModel)
                            : viewModel);
                    }
                    if (!this.UseLastItemAsFooter && this.ItemTemplateFooterId > 0)
                    {
                        list.Add(new MvxFooterSectionListItem(section as MvxViewModel));


                    }
                }

                base.SetItemsSource(list);
            }
        }

        protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object dataContext, int templateId)
        {

            var header = dataContext as MvxHeaderSectionListItem;
            if (this.ItemTemplateHeaderId > 0 && header != null)
            {
                return base.GetBindableView(convertView, header.ViewModel, this.ItemTemplateHeaderId);
            }
            var footer = dataContext as MvxFooterSectionListItem;
            if (this.ItemTemplateFooterId > 0 && footer != null)
            {
                return base.GetBindableView(convertView, footer.ViewModel, this.ItemTemplateFooterId);
            }
            if (this.ListView != null)
            {
                if (convertView != null)
                {
                    convertView.Click -= this.ViewOnClick;
                }
                var view = base.GetBindableView(convertView, dataContext, templateId);
                view.Click += this.ViewOnClick;
                var vm = dataContext as MissionListItemViewModel;
                var invite = vm.Item as MissionInviteStatus;
                if (invite != null && invite.GetType() == typeof(MissionInviteStatus)&&invite.UserAccepted)
                {
                    var headerView = view.FindViewById<TextViewWithFont>(Resource.Id.button1);
                  headerView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.button_red);
                }
               else

                {
                    var headerView = view.FindViewById<TextViewWithFont>(Resource.Id.button1);
                    headerView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.button_grey);
                }

                return view;
            }
            return base.GetBindableView(convertView, dataContext, templateId);
        }

        private void ViewOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var viewItem = sender as MvxBaseListItemView;

            if (this.ListView.ItemClick == null)
                return;

            var item = viewItem.DataContext;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            if (!this.ListView.ItemClick.CanExecute(item))
                return;

            this.ListView.ItemClick.Execute(item);
        }

        public event EventHandler<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs> DataSetChanged;
    }



    public class MvxHeaderSectionListItem
    {
        public MvxHeaderSectionListItem(MvxViewModel section)
        {
            this.ViewModel = section;
        }

        public MvxViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    }
    public class MvxFooterSectionListItem
    {
        public MvxFooterSectionListItem(MvxViewModel section)
        {
            this.ViewModel = section;
        }

        public MvxViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Custom listview

```
namespace Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views
{
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Util;
    using Android.Views;

    using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.ResourceHelpers;
    using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views;

    using MissionsApp.App.Droid;
    using MissionsApp.App.Droid.Controls;

    public class MvxSectionListView : MvxListView
    {
        public MvxSectionListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
            : this(context, attrs, new MvxSectionAdapter(context))
        {

        }

        public MvxSectionListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, MvxSectionAdapter adapter)
            : base(context, attrs,adapter)
        {
           // adapter.ItemTemplateId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadListItemTemplateId(context, attrs);
            adapter.ItemTemplateHeaderId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadAttributeValue(context, attrs, MvxAndroidBindingResource.Instance.ListViewStylableGroupId, Resource.Styleable.MvxListView_MvxItemHeaderTemplate);
            adapter.ItemTemplateFooterId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadAttributeValue(context, attrs, MvxAndroidBindingResource.Instance.ListViewStylableGroupId, Resource.Styleable.MvxListView_MvxItemFooterTemplate);
            adapter.ListView = this;
            //Adapter = adapter;
        }



        public override bool PerformItemClick(View view, int position, long id)
        {
            return true;
            //return base.PerformItemClick(view, position, id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the same error and I'm using tabs-(fragments). It happens randomly in my case too. But I'm using version 3.0.14 and also I have customised MvxTabsFragmentActivity. You can see the customisations I have done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973203/mvxtabsfragmentactivity-remove-tabs).

Comment: I also did some customization to the mvxtabsfragmentactivity - dont know if it could anything - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to set the custom adapter when creating the MvxListView. This can be done by inheriting the MvxListView, then override the ctor, and set your custom adapter there.